# How do I kill a hung ssh session within tmux

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux

Here's my setup:

```
Workstation==ssh=>jumphost(tmux with split panes)==ssh=>server1
                                                 ==ssh=>server2
```

If either of the two connections to the servers becomes unresponsive, how can I terminate them?

Sending `~.` is not a convenient option as it would terminate the first ssh session.

Comment: Is there some way for you to retrieve the PID ? Like running `top`, typing `L` and then `ssh` ? Then you could `kill -9 <pid>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to kill a nested ssh session without affecting the parent, the inner session needs to receive the escape key.

You start the escape sequence by pressing enter, followed by `~` then `~`; this sends an escape to the inner session. Then you can follow it up with `.` to kill the inner session.

Comment: You could also change the escape character for the inner and outer sessions.

Answer (score 4):

I think [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/747663/108618) is good, it would probably be my first choice. An alternative is to use what tmux provides, like this:

Type <kbd>prefix</kbd>,<kbd>x</kbd> (the default <kbd>prefix</kbd> is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>). Confirm you want to kill the pane.

Processes running in the pane will get [SIGHUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP). Regardless if `ssh` is a direct child of `tmux` server of if there's a shell between `tmux` and `ssh`, `ssh` should get SIGHUP and exit*.

There may be other processes that will get SIGHUP, in particular the shell (if any) between `tmux` and `ssh`. Ask yourself if it's OK for you.

While the other answer is specific to ssh and does not depend on tmux, this answer is specific to tmux and does not depend on ssh (it can be used to terminate other programs inside tmux).

---

<sup>* Unless it was run with `nohup` or so. The main job of `nohup` is to make a process immune to SIGHUP.</sup>